# Windows mobile 6.5 create mail program

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

Hey Helpers from Stackoverflow!

I am from the Netherlands, so sorry for my English, with that out of the way I have a question. I own a mc67(portable scanner) running windows mobile 6.5 professional, I am trying to make an application where I can scan some bar codes and email it. I am making the application in visual basic in visual studio 2008, why? I got the scanner only working correctly with vista where I already had vs 2008 installed. I found out that I can't use system.net.mail, I am not a Pro at  Visual basic but I know a bit, but I am  new to windows 6.5 mobile development. So my question is how do I make this work?

Thanks in advance.

-Kgeest

Answer (score 0):

First look at the sample code for barcode scanning coming with the EMDK (SDK) from Zebra/Motorola/Symbol.

When you are familar with barcode scanning, you can start to look at Windows Mobile Outlook Session to create an email and send by code (C# example at https://github.com/hjgode/eMdiMail/blob/master/eMdiMail/sendMail.cs).

If you have no programming experience, look for a software partner.

Comment: Thx Josef for your reply, there is already a piece of software named 'datawedge', it doesn't matter what kind of textbox I have open it types it in there if I scan a barcode.

 I will for sure take a look at the c# code, but is there any way of doing it in visualbasic?

I can't get a software partner because I am just a student. I don't own a company, I got the device from a good friend who had a company.

Comment: Using the DataWedge you have no control on where the Barcode Data is put in. You may use the mentioned C# code as a template for creating your VB code or use an online C# code to VB code converter.